# Image in ComboBox disappearing after item is selected

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a ComboBox and added labels to it so I can have text with an icon but the icons disappear after an item is selected, What have I done wrong?

Before Selection:

[image]

After Selection:

[image]

```java
ObservableList<Label> booruChoices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
booruChoices.add(new Label("Gelbooru", new ImageView("https://gelbooru.com/favicon.ico")));
booruChoices.add(new Label("Danbooru", new ImageView("https://i.imgur.com/7ek8bNs.png")));
booruSelector.getItems().addAll(booruChoices);
booruSelector.setCellFactory(param -> {
    return new ListCell<Label>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item != null) {
                setGraphic(item.getGraphic());
                setText(item.getText());
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first answer was not what you're asking for, my mistake.
You are using the same `ImageView` for a cell in the `ComboBox` and for the `ComboBox`'s button. An `ImageView` can be displayed in one place only.
You need to create a graphic node for each cell in your `ComboBox`. `Label` is not a good item type for a `ComboBox` as it represents a UI node not a data object.
Here is an example of a class that holds your data:

```java
public class MyData {
    private String name;
    private Image image;

    public MyData(String name, String imageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = new Image(imageUrl);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Then you can creat a `ComboBox` using that class:

```java
ComboBox<MyData> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
MyData data1 = new MyData("Gelbooru", "https://gelbooru.com/favicon.ico");
MyData data2 = new MyData("Danbooru", "https://i.imgur.com/7ek8bNs.png");
comboBox.getItems().addAll(data1, data2);
comboBox.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<>() {
    final ImageView graphicNode = new ImageView();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyData item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item == null || empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            graphicNode.setImage(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getName());
            graphicNode.setImage(item.getImage());
            setGraphic(graphicNode);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything, also I have to cast the getCellFactory to Listcell

Comment: If you don't want to change the item type, just create a new `ImageView` and use it as graphic inside the cell factory.

Comment: @kleopatra, that's correct since `updateItem()` will be called every time a cell is updated. I changed my code and created one instance of `ImageView` for each cell. If you have a better solution please share it with me. Thanks.

Comment: @fabian I totally agree with you, actually whenever I have a similar problem, I create my own cell. I tried to give the simplest way to solve the problem here.

Comment: @fabian I updated my answer, thanks for your advice. I was talking about extending `ListCell` and you're talking about those two lines, my mistake.